# Retrieve highscores from GAE based on list of friends

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a Facebook App that uses GAE as a backend, and implements a simple scoring system. The real model is a little more cluttered with level data and the possibility of multiple users, but a simplified version is as follows:

```
class score(db.Model):
    value = db.IntegerProperty()
    user = db.StringProperty()
```

I already display the global top ten scores, but **I also want the option of displaying the top ten scores of a user's friends**. In an SQL environment I would do something like SELECT * FROM scores WHERE user1 IN (...friendslist...) or user2 IN (...friendslist...) ORDER BY value LIMIT 10. In a non-relational database "IN" queries are costly, and in GAE specifically they are limited to blocks of 30 values at a time. Implementing a query this way is not ideal.

My current solution is to store each score with key_name = facebook id (*the app only stores their highest score, so there is no problem with duplicate keys*), and then use score.get_by_key_name(...friendslist...). The problems with this method are numerous: I have to query for every friend, and this returns an unsorted list of ALL friends' scores that then needs to be parsed with code.

By memcaching each score entity I lighten the load a little, but memcache won't scale well if the datastore becomes populated with many scores, and this is still an expensive and painful way to do what would be a simple operation in a relational database. **Is there a better way to do this in Google App Engine?**

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you write the **top ten scores** to the each user's entity?

User 1 has a new score 100!  Yeah!

User 1 has a list of 20 friends.

Obtain the list of 20 friends and add 100 into a top scores field of each entity(if it's one of the top 20).

Downside:  Every time a user has a new high score, you will be pulling the entities of all their friends and possibly updating them.   WATCH YOUR READ WRITE COSTS  Of course, if a user get's several high scores in a row, perhaps the friends values will be memcached.

Advantage:  You can timestamp each top score entry, track the last time the user played, and HIGHLIGHT new high scores since the user last played!  Just a thought...